# Java and Different Types of Stacks

Tags: java, data-structures, vector, stack

Currently the only stack I know anything about is Vector, I normally use this in place of an array but I understand that there is other types of stacks and they all suit different jobs.

The project I am currently working on requires me to be inserting objects in a certain position inside a stack, not always the front of the stack and I am under the impression that a Vector may not be the best class for this job.

Could somebody please give me a brief description of the other types of stacks available to me with the Java language and their advantages and disadvantages? Are these names homogeneous? E.g. Are they only used in the Java language or are they used as general terms in Computer Science?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

- A **stack** is an abstract data type characterized by LIFO behaviour or push/pop operations
- A **list** is an abstract data type characterized by having its elemets accessible through a numerical index.
- An **array** is a low-level implementation of a list
- **`java.util.List`** is the list type represented as a Java interface
- **`java.util.Deque`** is a Java interface that provides both LIFO and FIFO queue behaviour (and thus stack behaviour as a subset)
- **`java.util.Vector`** is an obsolete implementation of a list (based on an auto-resizing array) that should not be used anymore
- **`java.util.ArrayList`** is its modernized replacement
- **`java.util.Stack`** is an obsolete implementation of a stack that consists of adding some stack-like methods to a Vector, which is not a good way to do it.
- **`java.util.ArrayDeque`** is a modern implementation of the Deque interface
- **`java.util.LinkedList`** is a different implementation of a list (that also implements the Deque interface) that has a number of big disadvantages and should only be used in very specific cases (it is better when you need to insert or remove elemnts in the list very often).

Basically, if you want a stack, use the `Deque` interface and `ArrayDeque` as implementation class (except in the rare case where `LinkedList` is better). If you want a list, use `ArrayList`

Comment: he specifies that he will be doing inserts into the middle of the 'stack' often.

Comment: I don't think that a 'Stack' is the data structure that is actually needed. (Stacks, in the pure sense, only allow access to the element that was most recently added)

Comment: Note the Vector and Stack are obsolete because all operations are synchronized. The newer implementations are not synchronized and it's up to the user to synchronize as necessary or wrap the list with a    synchronized wrapper class (see java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()).

Comment: @jinguy: "often" is not specified :) Nor is the absence of random access.

Comment: Note that ArrayDeque is @since 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you are inserting things into the middle of your 'Stack.'  Then I would recommend using  `LinkedList`.

If you have already found the position that you need to enter a new element, the time to insert it is `O(1)`.  For a vector it is `O(n)` because you need to copy the backing array.

`LinkedList` also supports stack-like operations like adding onto the end, or popping off the end of the stack.

Take a look at the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for the data structure to see what it all offers.

To answer your last question.  The `LinkedList` is a very common data structure throughout computer science.  It is also very commonly used to implement stacks because the push and pop operations are constant time, `O(1)`.

Comment: A linked list is a rather memory-inefficient data structure and often not the best implementation of a stack; array-based lists provide amortized O(1) push and pop as well.

Comment: @Michael, but inserting into the middle of any array-backed structure has poor (O(n)) performance no matter what.

Comment: @jinguy: true, but they offer O(1) random access. If you need both (which is usually the case) then these cancel each other out, and memory efficiency makes the array-based implementation the better choice. Only if you often need to add/remove during iteration and don't need random access is the linked list a good choice.

Comment: Inserts on LinkedList are O(1), but finding the nth element in the middle of the list is still O(n). If the use case is that inserts are much less frequent than searches, the resize penalty of ArrayList may be irrelevant compared to a large number of linear searches. If almost all the work is searches, a HashSet or LinkedHashSet may be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at [this tutorial on the Java Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html), which refers to all of the main datatypes in the `java.util` package that you would use for things like this (Lists, Vectors, Maps, Trees, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation of `java.util.Stack` advises you to use one of the implementations of interface `java.util.Deque`, for example `java.util.ArrayDeque` or `java.util.LinkedList`.

A `LinkedList` is efficient for inserting elements in the middle and removing an element from the head or tail (but it's inefficient for looking up a random element).